# Nondisjunction of chromosomes

Tags: human-genetics

Why is it that nondisjunction of chromosomes usually happen in the egg, followed by in the sperm, followed by in the embryo? Why isn’t there also a chance that it occur in any cell cycle at any point?

So, why does it usually occur during meiosis and not in any cell undergoing mitosis, except perhaps early in the development of the embryo?

And

Why usually the egg and not the sperm?

Non disjunction can occur in meiosis I,II, or during mitosis when chromosomes fail to separate during anaphase which leads to aneuploidy daughter cells or germ cells.

Most resources, including McMaster pathophysiology review, explain the mechanism of failure and remark that most occur during the formation of the egg, a few during spermatogenesis, and very few during mitosis leading to mosaicism.

I can not find any resources that explain why the probability of aneuploidy would differ between oogenesis, spermatogenesis, and mitosis.

Why isn’t it that the cell cycle can malfunction and produce cancers but I have never heard of a tumor of aneuploidy cells?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: Haha. Ok. This is the first time I ever used stock exchange because I’ve always been successful finding the answers to all other questions. I just assumed this is where one goes when one had already exhausted all other avenues.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "nondisjunction" rather than "disjunction".
From "Genetics, Nondisjunction" at [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK482240/),

> Nondisjunction can occur during anaphase of mitosis, meiosis I, or meiosis II. During anaphase, sister chromatids (or homologous chromosomes for meiosis I), will separate and move to opposite poles of the cell, pulled by microtubules. In nondisjunction, the separation fails to occur causing both sister chromatids or homologous chromosomes to be pulled to one pole of the cell.

There's more info in the linked page.

Comment: Thank you for the article. It adds significant detail to my understanding. Is there any additional information as to why the nondisjunction occurs principally during meiosis and not mitosis and why it is more often during egg production and not sperm. I would have guessed that the probability of nondisjunction would be equally likely during any anaphase in any cell cycle. 

And, thank you for the correction. I edited the question to correct “disjunction” to “nondisjunction.”